# Need to copy customize fields from crm.lead to customer or partner

Tags: crm, odoo, lead

I have inherited an object from crm.lead and added some fields into it. its working fine but what I want that when I clicked on Create button to change lead to partner , those fields must be automatically copied from lead to customer. Remember I will also add those fields in customer as well. But unfortunately I yet could not able to find the exact location of where it is copying data from lead to partner. I tried to explore wizard of crm (crm_lead_to_partner) but I did not find any place. Kindly help me in this regards . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

take a look at how the [crm_base_contact module does](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~domsense/domsense-agilebg-addons/6.1/view/241/crm_base_contact/wizard/crm_lead_to_partner.py#L21):

```
class crm_lead2partner(osv.osv_memory):
    _inherit = 'crm.lead2partner'
    def _create_partner(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        partner_ids = super(crm_lead2partner, self)._create_partner(cr, uid, ids, context)
        [...do your stuff...]
        return partner_ids
```